# Span Text Alignment in CR

Tags: html, crystal-reports, alignment

What would be the working CR-Version for the following html tag:

```html
<p style="text-align: left">
  This text is left aligned<span style="float: right"
    >This text is right aligned</span
  >
</p>
```

When adding this as a function field into a HTML interpreted textbox I end up with  left aligned text only.

Answer (score 0):

on your style to center use style="text-align:center"

Comment: Like this? : '<p style="text-align:center">This text is left aligned<span style="float:right;">This text is right aligned</span></p>'  This does not change anything